# Android Hello World Exception

Tags: java, android, exception

I am trying to get this hello world android application working.
I go through this installation process and read about how easy this thing is to get up and running with a "Hello World" application. I run the simple hello world application (following every step exactly as it says) and POOF... nothing. I get an error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad version: standalone at com.android.sdkstats.sdkStatsService.normalizeVersion(sdkStatsService.java:467)

Any idea how to fix this? 
I have double checked my namespaces (all 3 of them) and also tried this using the XML editor...

Comment: Which "hello world android application"?

Comment: Could you post your source code?

Comment: Presumably http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/hello-world.html

Comment: some more details might help: Are you trying to run this on a device or the emulator? Do you have a more complete stack trace for the error that you saw? Etc...

Answer (score 2):

From Eclipse:

Windows => Preferences => Android

1) Ensure your SDK Location is correct

*2) Click "Apply" to populate the list of available SDK(s) for Android

Summary: Setting the SDK location is not enough, if you were to set the location, then click OK without Apply first, you would get the exception "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad version".